# how can I find value in sub multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [asset] => track [path] => media/promenade_web/AUDIO/promenade-arkadiev.mp3 [file_name] => promenade-arkadiev [permission_audio_play_synchronization] => Array ( [synchronization] => Array ( [constraint] => Array ( [numberOfMeasures] => Array ( [startMeasure] => 1 [number] => 10 ) [qualityOfResource] => medium ) [requirement] => Array ( ) [condition] => Array ( ) ) [play] => Array ( [constraint] => Array ( [numberOfMeasures] => Array ( [startMeasure] => 1 [number] => 10 ) [qualityOfResource] => medium [spatial] => iso3166:CH,IT [count] => 10 [datetime] => Array ( [start] => 2017-08-16 [end] => 2017-10-20 ) [accumulated] => P30D [format] => mp3,wav ) [requirement] => Array ( ) [condition] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [asset] => track [path] => media/promenade_web/AUDIO/promenade-arkadiev_lo.mp3 [file_name] => promenade-arkadiev_lo [permission_audio_play_synchronization2] => Array ( [play] => Array ( [constraint] => Array ( [numberOfMeasures] => Array ( [startMeasure] => 1 [number] => 10 ) [qualityOfResource] => medium [spatial] => iso3166:CH,IT [count] => 10 [datetime] => Array ( [start] => 2017-08-16 [end] => 2017-10-20 ) [accumulated] => P30D [format] => mp3,wav ) [requirement] => Array ( [prepay] => Array ( [amount] => 0.99 [currency] => EUR ) ) [condition] => Array ( ) ) ) ) )
```

How can I find a value with `foreach`, regardless of the number of subarrays?

I've tried with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
function recursive_array_search($needle, $haystack, $currentKey = '') {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $nextKey = recursive_array_search($needle,$value, $currentKey . '[' . $key . ']');
            if ($nextKey) {
                return $nextKey;
            }
        }
        else if($value==$needle) {
            return is_numeric($key) ? $currentKey . '[' .$key . ']' : $currentKey;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to get out of it?

Comment: i'm trying to get 'qualityOfresurce' value inside my array.

Comment: There are multiple instances of that key. Are you trying to get them all? If so, should they be associated with some other value from the entry? If not, are you trying to get a specific one? Which one?

Comment: The function i wrote it's not correct, i know, by the way i would find the values inside the array, but i don't know how many subarrays are inside the main array, because there are different file and array structure, is it possibile to use only one  recursive cycle?

Comment: Please provide a parsable code for your array. Use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 0):

I always use following on multi dimensional array

```
 $arr = array(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'nilesh'),array('id'=>2,'name'=>'ajay'));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr[array_search('nilesh', array_column($arr,'name'))]);
    echo "</pre>";
```